# JSch: Checking a private key file passphrase before trying to connect

Tags: ssh, jsch, ssh-keys

For quite a simple application that mostly depends on ssh connections made via JSch, I wanted to ask for the passphrase at the login screen, try to decrypt the private key and if it is wrong, go back to the login window.

I could not find the way to discover whether an invocation to

```
jsch.addIdentity(keyfile, prvkey, pubkey, passphrase);
```

ended properly, even if I can see in the code that the decryption has already been tried, and I suppose it already knows the passphrase is wrong.

Is there any way to detect the passphrase is correct BEFORE attempting to establish any session?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`KeyPair`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPair.html) class for your requirements as follows,

```
KeyPair kpair = KeyPair.load(jsch, prvkey, pubkey);
System.out.println(kpair.decrypt(passphrase));
```